# Remove Linked Master Account Of Mailbox Exchange 2013

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I am trying to remove a linked master account of a mailbox user in Exchange 2013 and having trouble doing so. Does anyone know the command in power shell to make this happen?

Thank you,

Comment: Which error & which problems? What did you see in the eventlog? We are missing a lot of details here to help you.

Comment: So I went to associate a user with a different users linked account and got the below message saying it could not due to it already having a linked master account.

Answer (score 0):

For the below, "blah@acme.com" should be the mail address on the mailbox you're trying to remove the master from. If this is the command that isn't working for you, you will need to provide error information.

```
Set-User -identity "blah@acme.com" -linkedmasteraccount $null
```